# maximum-likelihood estimation for P (X > λ) when xi ~ pois ( λ)

Tags: poisson-distribution, maximum-likelihood

Suppose X1, · · · , Xn are i.i.d. samples following Pois(λ) distribution. 
X is a random variable, X ∼ Pois(λ). 
I need help in finding the maximum-likelihood estimation for ρ = P (X > λ).

I tried to find the likelihood function, knowing the poisson distribution formula, but I'm not sure how to address the condition of X > λ. 
Chernoff's bound / Markov's inequality cannot be used, because inequality isn't suitable for finding the likelihood function.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well$-$known that MLE for $\lambda$ is the sample mean $\bar{X}$. Moreover, $$\rho=1-\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\lambda}\rfloor}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}$$ By the invariance property of the MLE, we see that the MLE of $\rho$ is $$\rho=1-\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\bar{X}}\rfloor}\frac{e^{-\bar{X}}{\bar{X}}^k}{k!}$$